# How can i render lineseries/contour/etc objects to array of pixel data?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an array of pixel data frames for use with VideoWriter.  I want to overlay lineseries/contour objects into each frame.  I don't want to make the movie by iteratively drawing each frame to a figure and capturing it with getframe, because that gives poor resolution and is slow.  I tried using getframe on a plot of just the contour, but that returns images scaled to the wrong size with weird margins, especially when using 'axis equal,' which I need.

Comment: If you have pixel data in your frames then you can set the pixel values for your lines and contours directly assuming you have the raw pixel data for your contours. Can you give an example of both the raw frame data and the contour data ?

Comment: the pixel data for the contours is what i'm asking how to get!  raw frame data is [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.writevideo.html#inputarg_images), contour data is a handle to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to accommodate feedback from OP**

Getting the contour data as pixel data is not trivial (if possible at all) since using `getframe` doesn't yield predictable results

What we can do is to extract the contour data and then overlay it on the pixel data frames, forcing them to be to the same scale and then do a `getframe` on the resultant merged image. This will at least ensure that they two data sets area aligned.

The following code shows the principle though you'd need to modify it for your own needs:

```
%% Generate some random contours to use
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);

[~,h] = contour(X,Y,Z);
```

This yields the following contours

[image]

Now we get the handles of the children of this image. These will all be 'patch' type objects

```
patches = get(h,'Children');
```

Also get the axis limits for the contours

```
lims = axis;
```

Next, create a new figure and render the pixel frame data into it
In this example I'm just loading an image but you get the idea.

```
%% Render frame data
figure
i = imread( some_image_file_png );
```

[image]

This image is actually 194 x 259 x 3. I can display it and rescale the X and Y axes using

```
%% Set image axes
image(flipdim(i,1),'XData',[lims(1) lims(2)],'YData',[lims(4) lims(3)]);
```

Note the use of flipdim() to vertically flip the image since the image Y-axis runs in the opposite sense to the contour Y axis. This gives me:

[image]

Now I can plot the contours (patches) form the contour plot over the top of the image in the same coordinate space

```
%% Plot patches
for p =1:length(patches)
    xd = get( patches(p), 'XData' );
    yd = get( patches(p), 'YData' );

    % This causes all contours to be rendered in white. You may 
    % want to play with this a little
    cd = zeros(size(xd));
    patch( xd, yd, cd, 'EdgeColor', 'w');
end
```

This yields

[image]

You can now use `getframe` to extract the frame. If it's important to have coloured contours, you will need to extract colour data from the original contour map and use it to apply an appropriate colouring in the overlaid image.

As a short cut, it's also possible to compile all patch data into a single MxN matrix and render with a single call to patch but I wrote it this way to demonstrate the process.

Comment: in principle yes, using bresenham or something, but i don't want to render them manually (anti aliasing, accounting for properties like color and linewidth, etc).  i want the pixel data as matlab would render it.

Comment: Not sure that this is doable by default. contourc generates the low level data for plotting contours. Since it is the Z value of the contour which determines the contour line, it will almost never be the case that X and Y are integral values so you (or someone) will always have to plot those contours into a 2D array.  Matlab does this of course but since you can scale the figure arbitrarily (and X and Y independently) I don't think there's a way that you can rely on somehow grabbing this data.

Comment: well the principle of getframe (on a plot of just the contour, set to the size of my pixel array) would suffice, if it worked.  but as is, it adds margins seemingly unpredictably.

Comment: thanks for all the effort, but as the OP states, i don't want to use getframe to generate each frame of the movie -- that is very slow and low resolution, and unnecessary since i already have all the frame pixel data.  also, you don't have to manually draw the patches to overlay contours on an image -- you can just use `hold on` and draw the contours into the same axes, or use copyobj.

Comment: Looks like you're stuck then! If you don't want to use e.g. Bresenham to render yourself and if `getframe` does't cut it. It sounds like you believe that there must be some way to extract the raw pixel data from a plot. It may be a good idea to update the OP to ask that specific question.

Comment: as my comment above states, getframe would suffice in principle (just done once on the contour), the problem is the unpredictable margins.  the OP doesn't require a getframe approach, any method to render contour objects to pixels (respecting properties including color/width/etc) is adequate.  obviously matlab knows how to do it, i think the best option would be access to that method -- perhaps some undocumented/hidden method on contour objects like `pixel_array = render(contour,size)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a Bresenham-esque solution based on the ContourMatrix.  Not ideal cuz doesn't handle line width, antialiasing, or any more than a single color.  But it's pretty efficient (not quite Bham efficient).

```matlab
function renderContour
clc
close all

x = randn(100,70);
[c,h] = contour(x,[0 0],'LineColor','r');
axis equal

if ~isnumeric(h.LineColor)
    error('not handled')
end

cs = nan(size(c,2),4);
k = 0;
ci = 1;
for i = 1:size(c,2)
    if k <= 0
        k = c(2,i);
    else
        if k > 1
            cs(ci,:) = reshape(c(:,i+[0 1]),[1 4]);
            ci = ci + 1;
        end
        k = k - 1;
    end
end

pix = renderLines(cs(1:ci-1,:),[1 1;fliplr(size(x))],10,h.LineColor);
figure
image(pix)
axis equal
end

function out = renderLines(cs,rect,res,color)
% cs   = [x1(:) y1(:) x2(:) y2(:)]
% rect = [x(1) y(1);x(2) y(2)]

% doesnt handle line width, antialiasing, etc
% could do those with imdilate, imfilter, etc.

test = false;
if test
    if false
        cs = [0 0 5 5; 0 5 2.5 2.5];
        rect = [0 0; 10 10];
    else
        cs = 100 * randn(1000,4);
        rect = 200 * randn(2);
    end

    res = 10;
    color = [1 .5 0];
end

out = nan(abs(res * round(diff(fliplr(rect)))));
cs = cs - repmat(min(rect),[size(cs,1) 2]);
d = [cs(:,1) - cs(:,3) cs(:,2) - cs(:,4)];
lens = sqrt(sum(d.^2,2));

for i = 1:size(cs,1)
    n = ceil(sqrt(2) * res * lens(i));
    if false % equivalent but probably less efficient
        pts = linspace(0,1,n);
        pts = round(res * (repmat(cs(i,1:2),[length(pts) 1]) - pts' * d(i,:)));
    else
        pts = round(res * [linspace(cs(i,1),cs(i,3),n);linspace(cs(i,2),cs(i,4),n)]');
    end
    pts = pts(all(pts > 0 & pts <= repmat(fliplr(size(out)),[size(pts,1) 1]),2),:);
    out(sub2ind(size(out),pts(:,2),pts(:,1))) = 1;
end
out = repmat(flipud(out),[1 1 3]) .* repmat(permute(color,[3 1 2]),size(out));

if test
    image(out)
    axis equal
end
end
```